# Check for certain text in multiple TexBoxes

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a prank antivirus program I'm making for a friend. Part of the software requires "activation" to remove the "virus". I have 4 TextBoxes when I click the button I want all 4 TexBoxes to be checked for the text "0000". When I have one TextBox it works great, but I need all 4 boxes to get checked before the message box appears. I hope this makes sense. [See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0pKS.jpg)

[Edit] I'm going to mention i'm a total noob at programming.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "0000" Then
            MsgBox("Registered")
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you want. Here's a very simple one which you can build on:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' check all the TextBoxes in the array. Return if one isn't valid
    For Each textbox As TextBox In {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4}
        If textbox.Text <> "0000" Then
            Return
        End If
    Next

    ' If all TextBox contains the valid string, this will appear
    MsgBox("Registered")
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Have fun!

EDIT:

To have 4 different strings: just chain 4 checks. Like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' If all TextBox contains the valid string, this will appear
    If TextBox1.Text = "0000" AndAlso TextBox2.Text = "1111" AndAlso TextBox3.Text = "2222" AndAlso TextBox4.Text = "3333" Then
        MsgBox("Registered")
        Me.Hide()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what if i want each box to have seperate texts

Comment: @nathanmorriss I updated the answer with this as another option.